# Error 503 after ezPublish install

Tags: ezpublish

I'm trying to install ezPublish.
I followed this : http://share.ez.no/blogs/thiago-campos-viana/tip-installing-ez-publish-5-on-ubuntu step by step but when I'm going to http://ez5 I get an error 503 Service Unavailable.

I upgrade memory limit to 512M but it doesn't work and I made right htaccess/VirtualHost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eZ Publish is kind of old now, did you try eZ Platform?
You can install it really easily with 
 eZ Launchpad: https://ezsystems.github.io/launchpad/

If you really need eZ Publish 5.x (legacy) I think this documentation is better and more recent: https://doc.ez.no/display/EZP/Installation